# Помогите расставить знаки препинания: Главные герои истории - два поколения одной семьи: отец и сын Гордеевы, Николай Михайлович и Евгений Николаевич

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложении: *Главные герои истории - два поколения одной семьи: отец и сын Гордеевы, Николай Михайлович и Евгений Николаевич.*

Comment: Татьяна, с пунктуацией вроде бы всё нормально, но "главные герои – два поколения", мягко говоря, как-то не очень... Нельзя ли попроще написать?

Comment: Герои — это конкретные люди, а поколения — это группы людей. Получается, что герои — это группы людей. Можно написать "из двух поколений".